# Android Studio crashes after importing Scenform asset with two animation files

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform, mixamo

I'm trying to import a Sceneform asset with two animation files. After I click finish and it starts to build, Android Studio crashes.

If I open Android Studio again and try to open the .sfb file, Android Studio crashes again.

The animation files are build with Mixamo.com

[image: Import Sceneform Asset before it crashes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Autodesk Maya with the FBX asset format and requirements from here https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/animation/obtaining-assets and it works now